# Invalid initial heap size errors while starting wso2 esb server with eclipse developer studio

Tags: java, eclipse, wso2, wso2-esb

Im getting an error while trying to start the wso2 esb with eclipse developer studio. How to overcome this?
This is the error

```
Invalid initial heap size: -XmsMEM_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help you: [WSO2 Developer Studio
Tooling for Platform RC2](http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2016-May/063698.html)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same Error when I tried to start the ESB 5.0.0 as a WSO2 carbon server inside eclipse (Eclipse Luna wso2 Developer studio features installed)

However, when I tried Developer Studio comes as a 'pre-packaged Eclipse which I downloaded from the links given in the Documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Installing+WSO2+ESB+Tooling I no longer encountered this issue.